# How To Correctly Tokio TcpStream to Listen and Send using ::connect

Tags: rust

I have this brief Connection Struct

```
ConnectionError {
    ConnectError(usize),
    SendError(usize),
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Connection {
    stream: Arc<Mutex<TcpStream>>,
    loc: usize,
}

impl Connection {
    async fn connect(loc:usize) -> Result<Connection, ConnectionError> {
        println!("Connecting");
        
        let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("3.85.107.207:80").await.map_err(|_| ConnectionError::ConnectError(loc))?;  

        //Start Listening
        let (r, w) = stream.split();


        Ok( Connection {
            stream: Arc::new(Mutex::new(stream)),
            loc: loc,
            }
        )
    }

    async fn Send(connection: Connection, string: String) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
        let mut stream = connection.stream.lock().await;
        stream.write_all(string.as_bytes()).await.map_err(|_| ConnectionError::SendError(connection.loc))?;
        Ok( () )
    }
}
```

I am having difficulty on where to begin on how to listen to the stream for incoming data. I can send data easily - all works well - just not sure on how to listen for input from the connection.

Secondary Question:

Should I be using a 1a) `TcpStream` combined with a `TcpListener`? Can you even have 2 connections like that one port? I'm coming from a python-ish understanding where I can just listen and send over the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

A `TcpListener` has an [`accept`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.4.0/tokio/net/struct.TcpListener.html#method.accept) function that returns a `Result<(TcpStream, SocketAddr)>` if/when a connection is received.

That's the stream you use to communicate with the remote client. Typically you hand this off via a `spawn`.

A given port can have an effectively unlimited number of connections to it provided the incoming IPs are different as well *and* you have enough filehandles to accommodate it. There's no limit in the TCP stack per-se.

Comment: So this is my Client - I connect to a Server with this client, but I would like to not only send information, but also obtain information from the Server. I already have the `TcpStream` with the ` let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("3.85.107.207:80").await.map_err(|_| ConnectionError::ConnectError(loc))?;  ` but how can I get it where I can listen for information as well?

Comment: A `TcpStream` is a bi-directional communication channel, so you can send and receive over it until it's closed. The client doesn't "listen", at least not in TCP parlance, that's a term reserved for waiting for connections on a given socket. The client "reads".

Comment: You don't need to split the connection like you've done, but if you do you end up with a write-only, and a read-only part. This can be useful in some scenarios, but perhaps not the one you're in.

Comment: Understood - I bet that's where I was misunderstanding. Any guidance on how to read data in once I connect with the `TcpStream` as well as be able to send data? I have the function to send data - and it works as necessary for my program. Just not sure how to read data from the connection

Comment: Normally you write, then flip over to `await` some reading. The [`tokio_stream`](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/0.1.5/tokio_stream/) module is really helpful here as you can define a protocol at a higher-level. There's numerous examples available on setting up a read/write client-server protocol.

Comment: Can I not write and send at the same time?

Comment: You can, but usually there's some framing involved so you need to check that the server correctly received your write, you can't just keep pumping it and hope everything works out in the end. In practice most systems end up with a write/read or read/write type loop.

Comment: Whatcha mean by the loop? Like why a loop for that and what does it accomplish?

Comment: Most every protocol has some kind of "send command, await response" type pattern to it. The structure you need depends on what you're doing here.

Comment: Hrm - interesting.

Comment: Line-based protocols are the easiest to start with. For things like pub-sub it can get more tricky, as you never know when to read, so you must always be peeking at the incoming data to see what's coming down.

Comment: Where are these examples at?'

Comment: Part of the [Tokio project](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/tree/master/examples).